# Why can't I break out of this itertools infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, posix

In the REPL, we can usually interrupt an infinite loop with a sigint, i.e. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and regain control in the interpreter.

```
>>> while True: pass
... 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>>
```

But in this loop, the interrupt seems to be blocked and I have to kill the parent process to escape.

```
>>> *x, = itertools.repeat('x')
^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^\^\^\^\^\^Z^Z^Z^Z
```

Why is that?

Comment: Relevant bug in the Python tracker: http://bugs.python.org/issue26351

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `KeyboardInterrupt` is checked after each Python instruction. `itertools.repeat` and the tuple generation is handled in C Code. The interrupt is handled afterwards, i.e. never.

Comment: Indeed. `list(itertools.repeat('x'))` also hangs the interpreter, but putting it in the background and sending a plain `TERM` signal does kill the interpreter correctly.

Comment: I agree. I initially thought the hanging had to do with memory allocation.  However the memory usage doesn't grow for `list(itertools.groupby(itertools.repeat(1))` and it hangs the interpreter as well.